# How to share Discord.py code with Github without exposing code, while still having your bot run on Heroku

Tags: github, heroku, discord, bots, discord.py

So I host my Discord.py bot on Heroku. I also want to continue updating the source code on Github. Whenever I want to update the source code, I have to remove my .env file with the token in it so I can upload it to Github, then I would have to add the file *again* to push it to Heroku. Is there any way to have the bot run on Heroku without having to add the file to Git before doing so?

Answer (score 1):

You can store your token as a config variable in Heroku and it will automatically set it as an environment variable in your Dyno, you do not need your .env file at all.

See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars